# where can I find example of boost::multi_index range deletion

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I'm looking for example code for the deletion of elements in a multi_index container, using an ordered_non_unique range. I've found a single example on the boost site, which I can't duplicate with my code. I'm hoping for examples not written by the library's author, which highlight real-world C.R.U.D. usage of this index / iterator combo.

Comment: A `boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique` index models `std::multiset`, you can probably find more examples of `multiset`

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me well, this is the first time I'm explicitly banned from providing an answer

Comment: How does that happen?

Comment: I am the library's author.